# Republish Android App which is made private

Tags: android, google-play-console

My app was publicly available but in experimenting something have now hosted it as private.
I am not getting steps to again publish the app so that its publicly available.
Can someone please help

Comment: okay,so you make it private or unpublished.

Comment: private @MohitJadav86